# Trying to run a web app using Django REST framework as a backend and getting error message after "./manage.py migrate"?

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm having trouble building a project that uses React as a frontend and the Django Rest framework as a backend (Django/Python is new to me).

I'm following the build instructions on the README.md

This is exactly what I did:

1. git clone https://github.com/glenstarchman/itcc.git
2. cd itcc
3. git checkout development
4. cd backend
5. virtualenv -p python3.6 ./venv
6. source ./venv/bin/activate
7. pip3 install -r requirements.txt
8. createuser itcc
9. createdb -O itcc -E UTF-8 itcc
10. ./manage.py migrate

after running that last (10th) command, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[....]
 from ..models.locations import Location
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.models.locations'
```

Any ideas on how to make this error message go away? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The repository is not public, so it's hard to tell. But you should start by trying to fix that bad import line. It points to a file that's not there.

Comment: looks like a module is missing but I'm not clear on how to download it...I thought about doing something like 'pip install api.models.location' but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module 'api.models.locations' couldn't be found. It is created by the author itself, not a python package that is available/published on Pip.

Solution: Ask the backend author